# Why onLongclicklistener does no work in onBindviewholder with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onlongclicklistener

I have looked for solutions to this problem but cannot find an answer.
I can get my `onClickListener` to work (Kotlin) from inside the `onBindViewHolder` of my Adapter but the `onLongClickListener` (Kotlin) does not respond, even though the code is not showing an error

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val ingredientdisplay=displayItems[position]
    holder.setData(ingredientdisplay,position)
    runningTotal=runningTotal+holder.itemView.tvcost.text.toString().toDouble()
    println ("running total $runningTotal")

    val intent = Intent("message_from_displayadapter")
    intent.putExtra("runningtotal", runningTotal)
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent)   

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {view->
        println("longclick")
        true
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(context, ChooseIngredientsActivity::class.java)
        ContextCompat.startActivity(context, intent, null)
    }
}
```

I am just trying to `println` or run a `Toast` but nothing happens.

I don't understand why? Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use `println` which does not actually print messages to Android's [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) but only to the standard output; instead use the [`Log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) class that Android provides to log statements to the logcat, which supports specifying a tag that makes it easier for you to search for the specific message you logged by that tag.

Comment: You should also use addition assignment (aka `+=`) to the line where you assigned a variable to its variable added with a double. (E.g. `runningTotal += /* value to add */` instead of `runningTotal = runningTotal + /* value to add */`) (Check out the Kotlin docs for more operators that the language supports here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols)

Comment: Edric .thank you both valid points but they do not answer the question or effect the running of the code.

Answer (score 0):

First don't put your `onClicklistiner` in `onBindViewHolder` it's not good practice, use update your Adapter Class like this one also `OnLongclicklistiner` is working fine

```
class NewsAdapter (val context: Context, private val arrayList: ArrayList 
<NewsModel>):
RecyclerView.Adapter <NewsAdapter.Holder> () {

companion object {
   // val TAG: String = OperationAdapter::class.java.simpleName
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder (parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
    return Holder (LayoutInflater.from (parent.context ).inflate (R.layout.newsitemlist , parent, false))
}

override fun getItemCount (): Int = arrayList. size

override fun onBindViewHolder (holder: Holder, position: Int) {

    val mynews= arrayList[position]
    holder.setData(mynews, position)

}

inner class Holder (itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder (itemView) {
    private var currentnews: NewsModel? = null
    private var currentPosition: Int = 0


    init {
        //The click listener

        itemView.cardview.setOnClickListener {

            val i = Intent(context,NewsReaderActivity::class.java)
            i.putExtra("body",currentnews!!.body)
            i.putExtra("title",currentnews!!.title)
            context.startActivity(i)

        }

        itemView.cardview.setOnLongClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(context,"Long Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            true
        }


        //the end of the init
    }

    //getting data from model and bind it into View
    fun setData(news: NewsModel?, position: Int) {
        news?.let {
            itemView.newstitle.text = news.title
            itemView.body.text = news.body
            itemView.txtdate.text = news.ndate

        }

        this.currentnews = news
        this.currentPosition = position
          }
       }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have done as you suggested but still only the onClicklistener is working. The onLongClickListener just is not responding.

Comment: Edit your question and post entire your Adapter Class

Answer (score 0):

I have moved the listeners to the inner class the code for the complete adaper is below. Still the onLongClicListener is not responding.

class RecipiesDisplayAdapter(val context:Context, val displayItems:List):RecyclerView.Adapter(){

```
var runningTotal:Double=0.00

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
   val view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recipedisplay_list,parent,false)
    return MyViewHolder(view)

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return  displayItems.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val ingredientdisplay=displayItems[position]
    holder.setData(ingredientdisplay,position)
    runningTotal=runningTotal+holder.itemView.tvcost.text.toString().toDouble()
    println ("running total $runningTotal")

    val intent = Intent("message_from_displayadapter")
    intent.putExtra("runningtotal", runningTotal)
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent)

}


inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

 private var  currentIngredientDisplay:IngredientDisplay?=null
 private var  currentPosition:Int=0


    init {

        itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
            Log.i ("clicked ", "longclick")
            context.showToast("longClicked")
             true
        }


        itemView.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(context, ChooseIngredientsActivity::class.java)
            ContextCompat.startActivity(context, intent, null)

        }

    }

   fun setData(ingredientdisplay: IngredientDisplay?, pos:Int){

       val fromrate=getfromdb(ingredientdisplay!!.unitPurchased)
       val torate =getfromdb(ingredientdisplay!!.unitPerRecipe)

       val minunitcost= ingredientdisplay!!.costPurchased/ingredientdisplay!!.quantityPurchased/fromrate
       val costperrecipe=minunitcost*ingredientdisplay!!.quantityPerRecipe*torate
       val s = String.format( "%.2f", costperrecipe);

       val pdu=ingredientdisplay!!.quantityPerRecipe.toString()+" "+ingredientdisplay!!.unitPerRecipe


       ingredientdisplay?.let {

           itemView.tvIngredientName.text = ingredientdisplay!!.ingredientName
           itemView.tvcost.text = s
           itemView.tvqty.text = pdu
       }
       this.currentPosition=pos
       this.currentIngredientDisplay=ingredientdisplay

   }

    fun getfromdb (unit:String) :Double{

        var sendback:String=""

        context.database.use {
            select("Units", "convertionrate")
                .`whereSimple`("unitname = ?", unit)

                .exec {


                    parseList(DoubleParser).forEach{

                        println("result $it")

                        val resu= it.toString()

                        sendback=resu
                    }
                }

        }

        return sendback.toDouble()
    }

}

}
```

I cannot figure out why!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I made a rookie mistake. I added all the onclicklisteners to my adapters. Then later started to add onlongclicklisteners to them. Belive it or not. I was setting it in the wrong adapter. Appologies for your trouble however your answers where helpful.

Answer (score 0):

context does not work sometimes or in the newer version
so you can use also

```
Toast.makeText(it.context, "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```